# Pyomo - ConstriantList

Tags: pyomo

Invalid constraint expression. The constraint expression resolved to a trivial Boolean (True) instead of a Pyomo object. Please modify your rule to return Constraint.Feasible instead of True.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to or.stackexchange. Your post does not contain a question. If you edit your original post to include the code that produced the error and a question, you will probably get a useful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to tell what exactly is going on as your complete model is not visible. A possible cause is that both $lhs$ and $rhs$ are numbers, containing no variables which Python evaluates as a bool. Like $23 <= 28$. For debugging i suggest printing $lhs$ and $rhs$ before adding the constraints.